# Visual Studio 2022 ReSharper Jquery intellisense not showing

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, visual-studio-2022

I installed Visual Studio 2022 with the ReSharper extension, but the jquery intellisense is  not showing. I already check the checkbox of `Havascript and TypeScript`, `Protobuf` and `CSS Language` in Resharper options.

In same solution project, this is Visual Studio 2019 with ReSharper:

[image: VS2019 work]

However, in Visual Studio 2022 with ReSharper (version 2023.1.1):

[image: Jquery intellisense not working]

Jquery intellisense not working (not showing "val")

How can I fix this issue? Is there an option to enable it?

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but maybe still helpful. I found a post here https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/10879324965522-New-version-breaks-CSS-intellisene claiming that resharper CSS intelisense is disabled per default starting with version 2023.1.

In my case enabling ReSharper => Options => Environment => Products & Features => the "CSS" checkbox did the job. After the restart my bootstrap and jquery support started working again

Comment: Thank you for reply. But I'm already enable this features in options. It's working at `Javascript`, but not working at `JQuery`. Does your intellisense work at `JQuery` ?